# JavaScript create blank placeholder image dynamically

Tags: javascript, image

I need to dynamically create a blank placeholder image in JavaScript, width and height unknown until runtime.

The generated image should be fully transparent with the dimensions given in PNG format.

It is important that the actual generated image itself has the dimensions given, merely setting the width and height attributes of the generated img tag is not sufficient.

I need something like this:

```
const createImage = (width, height) => {
  const img = new Image()
  // img must have width and height in px as specified (see above proviso)
  // img must also be a transparent PNG
  return img
}

const img1 = createImage(100, 100)
const img2 = createImage(640, 480)
```

How can I do this?

PS I know I could probably find an online service to do this for me, but I want to avoid the overhead of an HTTP call to get the image.

Comment: `const img = new Image(width, height)` ?

Comment: this fails to meet the proviso in the question but thanks anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an HTML Canvas and fill it with a transparent rectangle, then convert it to a data url and attach it to an Image element.

```js
const createImage = (width, height) => {

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = width
  canvas.height = height
  
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

  const img = new Image(width, height)
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL()

  return img
}

const img1El = document.getElementById('img1')
const img2El = document.getElementById('img2')
const img1 = createImage(100, 50)
const img2 = createImage(20, 50)
img1El.src = img1.src
img2El.src = img2.src
```

```css
#img1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#img2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1">
<img id="img2">

<div>Right click an image above and select Save image as...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I made your code into a code snippet to prove it works - many thanks, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You were close, the first and second arguments of the Image constructor are the width and height:

```
        const createImage = (width, height) => {
        const img = new Image(width, height)
        return img
        }

        const img1 = createImage(100, 100)
        const img2 = createImage(640, 480)
        document.body.append(img1, img2)
```

Comment: When I console.log img I get <img width="100" height="100"> which is essentially just the img tag with the width and height attributes set - this is not what I want as stated in the question - I want an actual image width a src whose width is 100px and height is 100px - but thanks for trying

Comment: So you want to dynamically create an image of that size?

Comment: Ah someone has posted the answer you're looking for, that makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

```
function createImage(width, height) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.style.minWidth = `${width}px`;
  img.style.minHeight = `${height}px`;
  return img;
}


const img1 = createImage(100, 100)
const img2 = createImage(640, 480)
document.body.appendChild(img1)
```